# How to execute a very huge MySQL query? (it took several days then stop without success)

Tags: mysql, database

I need to execute a query in DATABASE2 (60G) that fetch data from DATABASE1 (80G). Some tables have 400M rows in both databases.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO product_to_category (
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id, pds.nodeid
 FROM product p 
JOIN DATABASE2.article_links al ON al.supplierid=p.manufacturer_id
 AND al.datasupplierarticlenumber=p.mpn
 JOIN DATABASE2.passanger_car_pds pds ON al.productid=pds.productid
)
```

The execution took more than 6 days!!! then stooped without inserting any row into table.

```
[root@XXXX ~]# mysqladmin pr
+--------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id     | User        | Host              | db          | Command | Time   | State        | Info                                                                                                 |
+--------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 939    | root        | localhost         | mws_autocms | Query   | 408622 | Sending data | INSERT IGNORE INTO product_to_category (
SELECT p.product_id, pds.nodeid
FROM product p
JOIN DATABASE2 |
| 107374 | root        | localhost         |             | Query   | 0      | starting     | show processlist                                                                                     |
+--------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

if I run the query with **LIMIT 100** at the end, it executes the query and insert data to table.

I tuned MySQL to:

```
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 2
innodb_log_file_size            = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 512M
query_cache_size                = 0
query_cache_type                = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 12G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 8
innodb_read_io_threads          = 16
innodb_write_io_threads         = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_large_prefix             = 1
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_file_format              = Barracuda
max_allowed_packet              = 1024M
lower_case_table_names          = 1
```

Without any success.

Any help/advice to run this query please. I've been struggling for weeks.

Here the output of the **EXPLAIN** command

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | partitions | type | possible_keys                                          | key                       | key_len | ref                                             | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | INSERT      | product_to_category | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                                                   | NULL                      | NULL    | NULL                                            |    NULL |     NULL | NULL                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p                   | NULL       | ALL  | manufacturer_id                                        | NULL                      | NULL    | NULL                                            | 5357582 |   100.00 | Using temporary          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | al                  | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,productid,supplierid,datasupplierarticlenumber | datasupplierarticlenumber | 100     | mws_autocms.p.mpn,mws_autocms.p.manufacturer_id |      56 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pds                 | NULL       | ref  | productid                                              | productid                 | 4       | mws_tecdoc_2018_4_fr.al.productid               |    1322 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Fetching that amount of data is a problematic one, did u try pagination, pagination is the way for this. *there are lots of pagination example avaliable in google*

Comment: Make sure your tables are properly indexed (your execution time indicates that they might not) and provide the execution plan (the output of `explain insert ignore into ...`).

Comment: I just updated the question and added EXPLAIN command

Answer (score 0):

This is way too broad to answer here. My response here is really a comment - but its a bit long.

"I've been struggling for weeks" - and this is all you have to show for it?

> I tuned MySQL to:

Why? How? What hardware is this running on?

Given that there are several options here which require a restart, does that mean you have exclusive use the DB instance? If so, why are using O_DIRECT?

Why the join when you are only using the data from one table?

> Some tables have 400M rows in both databases.

You need to have a better understanding of cardinality or how to communicate this.

> then stooped without inserting any row into table

Why did it stop without inserting? What did you do to investigate?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. for parameters, I'm not a developer. my developer/database designer recommended these parameters. For 400M rows, I just wanted to says 2 huge databases.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I got stuck with things like this I start to break down the requirement and introduce intermediary steps into my plan. From reading your question, you need to:

1) Join data from multiple sources together and then
2) Insert that resultset into another database.

You can therefore break it down into multiple steps giving the database less to do before it times out.

Create a table of ONLY the data you want to insert (one query, something like the following)

```
CREATE TABLE dataToImport AS
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id, pds.nodeid
 FROM product p 
JOIN DATABASE2.article_links al ON al.supplierid=p.manufacturer_id
 AND al.datasupplierarticlenumber=p.mpn
 JOIN DATABASE2.passanger_car_pds pds ON al.productid=pds.productid
```

Then import that data:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO product_to_category SELECT product_id, nodeid FROM dataToImport
```

It's a bit of a crude operation, but it means the database is doing less work in a single hit, so you might find it solves your problem.

If it still doesn't work, you need to understand how big the resultset of that SELECT query is, so run your SELECT on it's own first and look at the output.

Comment: I'll try this and return back to you. but if I create a TEMPORARY table from my query, does MySQL insert directly to the TEMP table or write to a file then to TEMP table. otherwise, I'll get the same result.

Comment: If you've got the disk space use a physical table then you aren't filling up all your buffers/RAM. If you're only selecting two fields even 400M rows won't be that big I wouldn't have thought. GIve it a try and see how you get on. As I said it's a bit crude but I suspect you won't be running this regularly?

Comment: YES, I run this query once just to import products form a database. I'll run it 1/2 times a year.

Comment: Cool - see how you get on with my suggestion